# list all records from one custom taxonomy starting with one letter i.e A

Tags: wordpress-theming, custom-taxonomy

I want to list all records in one custom taxonomy start with only A or B. Below code is to list all record with all letters.

Here is the code to list all record with one custom taxonomy with all letters in groups. Example,

**A**

> Aajkacatch (0)
>   Aajkiitem (0)
>   Aamzie (0)
>   Aaneri (0)
>   Aaramshop (0)
>   Abaaya (0)

**B**

> B.LAB (0)
>   Baby-Republic (0)
>   Babyoye (45)
>   Bank-Bazaar (1)

```
    <?php 
        // Template Name: Store Template


        // get all the stores
        $stores = get_terms(APP_TAX_STORE, array('hide_empty' => 0, 'child_of' => 0, 'pad_counts' => 0, 'app_pad_counts' => 1));
        // get ids of all hidden stores 
        $hidden_stores = clpr_hidden_stores();
        $list = '';
        $groups = array();


        if ($stores && is_array($stores) ) {

    // unset child stores
    foreach($stores as $key => $value)
    if($value->parent != 0)
          unset($stores[$key]);

    foreach($stores as $store)
        $groups[mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($store->name, 0, 1))][] = $store;

    if (!empty($groups)) :

        foreach($groups as $letter => $stores) {
      $old_list = $list;
      $letter_items = false;
            $list .= "\n\t" . '<h2 class="stores">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $letter ) . '</h2>';
            $list .= "\n\t" . '<ul class="stores">';

            foreach($stores as $store) {
                if (!in_array($store->term_id, $hidden_stores)) {
                    $list .= "\n\t\t" . '<li><a href="' . get_term_link($store, APP_TAX_STORE) . '">' . apply_filters('the_title', $store->name). '</a> (' . intval($store->count) . ')</li>';
          $letter_items = true;
        }
            }   

            $list .= "\n\t" . '</ul>';

      if(!$letter_items)
        $list = $old_list;
        }

    endif;

        } else {

    $list .= "\n\t" . '<p>' . __('Sorry, but no stores were found.', 'appthemes') .'</p>';

        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

While it wouldn't be the most efficient way, you could easily just check the first letter of the store name.

change:

```
if (!in_array($store->term_id, $hidden_stores)) {
```

to:

```
if (!in_array($store->term_id, $hidden_stores)  ) {
  $first_letter = substr( $store->name, 0, 1 );
  if ( $first_letter == 'A' || && $first_letter == 'B' )
```

That would ensure you're only listing A and B items.